# Show that this is indeed a functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, proof-writing

my question is about how to prove that the following is indeed a functor, I will describe it as follows:

Let $\mathbb{V}$ denote the category of F-vector spaces.Given $V \in Ob(\mathbb{V})$ let:

$$V^{*}= L(V,F)$$

where $L(V,W)$ denotes the set of all F-linear maps from $V$ to $W$, now for each F-linear map:

$$f: V \to W$$

we define

$$W^{*} \to V^{*}$$
$$(\phi: W \to F) \to (\phi f: V \to W \to F)$$

Is this really a functor (well I have my doubt, because I don't know how to prove all the characteristics, I took them from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor ; the first one is by construction but the other properties I don not know how to justificate them)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Note: $\phi f$ this is composition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try applying the definition word by word. You already have a map on objects $V\to V^*$. Now:

Let $\phi\in V^*$. Then by your definition $(\text{id}_V)^*(\phi) = \phi \circ \text{id}_V = \phi$. This indeed proves that $(\text{id}_V)^*=\text{id}_{V^*}$.

You should try yourself to show that $(f\circ g)^*=g^*\circ f^*$.

---

Now consider $g\colon V\to W$ and $f\colon W\to Z$, so that $f \circ g\colon V\to Z$. Then let $\phi \in Z^*$ and observe that
$$
(f\circ g)^*(\phi) = \phi \circ (f \circ g) = (\phi \circ f) \circ g
= f^*(\phi)\circ g = g^*(f^*(\phi)) = (g^* \circ f^*)(\phi)
$$

Comment: Thank you AP a lot if I hace trouble can I ley you know?

Comment: Sure! Just comment here if you need further help in working it out.

Comment: Well I think I got it, because we have that $(fg)^{*}=(fg)(\phi)$ and we can distribute the composition and we are done isn't :)

Comment: That's the gist of it, but in your comment you post-composed by $f\circ g$, while in in your definition you are pre-composing (this is what gives contravariance, by the way)... do you see this?

Comment: mmmm I don't see it :(

Comment: Well I have $(fg)( \phi)=(g \phi)(f \phi ) $ and that is what we want isn't ?

Comment: Nope... $(f\circ g)^*(\phi) = \phi \circ (f \circ g) = \dotsb$

Comment: well then that is what we wanted?, Can you post it explicit please :)